# Maximum-Likelihood Estimation of three parameter reverse Weibull model implementation in R

Tags: r, statistics, mle, weibull, log-likelihood

I'm implementing a Maximum-Likelihood estimation in R for a three parameter reverse Weibull model and have some troubles to get plausible results, which include:
Bad optimization results, unwanted optimx behaviour. Beside these I wonder, how I could make use of parscale in this model.

Here is my implementation attempt:

To generate data I use the probabilty integral transform:

```
#Generate N sigma*RWei(alph)-mu distributed points        
gen.wei <- function(N, theta) {
      alph <- theta[1]
      mu <- theta[2]
      sigma <- theta[3]
      return(
        mu - sigma * (- log (runif(N)))**(1/alph)
      )
    }
```

Now I define the Log-Likelihood and negative Log-Likelihood to use optimx optimization:

```
#LL----
ll.wei <- function(theta,x) {
  N <- length(x)
  alph <- theta[1]
  mu <- theta[2]
  sigma <- theta[3]
  val <- sum(ifelse(
    x <= mu,
    log(alph/sigma) + (alph-1) * log( (mu-x)/sigma) - ( (mu-x)/sigma)**(alph-1),
    -Inf
  ))
  return(val)
}
#Negative LL----
nll.wei <- function(theta,x) {
  return(-ll.wei(theta=theta, x=x))
         }
```

Afterwards I define the analytical gradient of the negative LL. Remark: There are points at which the negative LL isn't differentiable (the upper end-point mu)

```
gradnll.wei <- function(theta,x) {
  N <- length(x)
  alph <- theta[1]
  mu <- theta[2]
  sigma <- theta[3]
  argn <- (mu-x)/sigma
  del.alph <- sum(ifelse(x <= mu,
    1/alph + log(argn) - log(argn) * argn**(alph-1),
    0
  ))
  del.mu <- sum(ifelse(x <= mu,
    (alph-1)/(mu-x) - (alph-1)/sigma * argn**(alph-2),
    0))
  del.sigma <- sum(ifelse(x <= mu,
    ((alph-1)*argn**(alph-1)-alph)/sigma,
    0))
  return (-c(del.alph, del.mu, del.sigma))
}
```

Finally I try to optimize using the optimx package and the methods Nelder-Mead (derivative free) and BFGS (my LL is kinda smooth, there's just one point, which is problematic).

```
      #MLE for Weibull
       mle.wei <- function(start,sample) {
      optimx(
        par=start,
        fn = nll.wei,
        gr = gradnll.wei,
        method = c("BFGS"),
        x = sample
      )
    }
    theta.s <- c(4,1,1/2) #test for parameters
    sample <- gen.wei(100, theta.s) #generate 100 data points distributed like theta.s
mle.wei(start=c(8,4, 2), sample) #MLE Estimation
```

To my surprise I get the following error:

```
Error in optimx.check(par, optcfg$ufn, optcfg$ugr, optcfg$uhess, lower,  : 
  Cannot evaluate function at initial parameters
```

I checked manually: Both nll and gradnll are finite at the initial parameters...
If i switch to optim instead of optim**x** I get a result, but a pretty bad one:

```
 $par
[1] 8.178674e-01 9.115766e-01 1.745724e-06

$value
[1] -1072.786

$counts
function gradient 
     574      100 

$convergence
[1] 1

$message
NULL
```

So it doesn't converge. If I don't supply the gradient to BFGS, there isn't a result. If I use Nelder-Mead instead:

```
$par
[1] 1.026393e+00 9.649121e-01 9.865624e-18

$value
[1] -3745.039

$counts
function gradient 
     502       NA 

$convergence
[1] 1

$message
NULL
```

So it is also very bad...

My questions are:

1. Should I instead of defining the ll outside of the support as -Inf give it a very high negative value like -1e20 to circumvent -Inf errors or does it not matter?
2. Like the first one but for the gradient: technically the ll isn't defined outside of the support but since the likelihood is 0 albeit constant outside of the support, is it smart to define the gradnll as 0 outside?
   3.I checked the implementation of the MLE estimator *fgev* from the *evd* package and saw that they use the *BFGS* method but don't supply the gradient even though the gradient does exist. Therefore my question is, whether there are situations where it is *contraproductive* to supply the gradient since it isn't defined everywhere (like my and the evd case)?
3. I got an error of "argument x matches multiple formal arguments" type in optimx but not in optim, which surprised me. What am I doing wrong in supplying my functions and data to the optimx function?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re 3:  That's kind of a bug in `optimx`, but one that's hard to avoid.  It uses `x` as a variable name when calculating a numerical gradient; you also use it as an "additional parameter" to your functions.  You can work around that by renaming your argument, e.g. call it `xdata` in your functions.

Re 1 & 2:  There are several techniques to handle boundary problems in optimization.  Setting to a big constant value tends not to work:  if the optimizer goes out of bounds, it finds the objective function really flat.  If the exact boundary is legal, then pushing the parameter to the boundary and adding a penalty sometimes works.  If the exact boundary is illegal, you might be able to reflect:  e.g. if mu > 0 is a requirement, sometimes replacing mu by abs(mu) in the objective function gets things to work. Sometimes the best solution is to get rid of the boundary by transforming the parameters.

Edited to add some more details:

For this problem, it looks to me as though transformations of the parameters might work.  I think `alpha` and `sigma` must both be positive. Setting `alpha <- exp(theta[1])` and `sigma <- exp(theta[3])` will guarantee that.  Limits on `mu` are harder, but I think `mu > max(xdata)` is needed, so `mu <- max(xdata) + exp(theta[2])` should keep it in bounds.  Of course, making these changes messes up your gradient formula and starting values.

As to resources:  I'm afraid I don't know any.  This advice is based on years of painful experience.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
Re 3: Astounding! But thank you for telling me. So it is actually easy to fix.

Re 1& 2: Could you get a little bit more in detail or link me to a ressource, where you got your knowledge from? I conclude from your answer, that transformations are helpful. What transformations do you mean? Adding a penalty to the Log-L might work, but changes my MLE to a penalized MLE doesn't it?

Comment: Regarding your edit:
I understand. You are right: alpha and sigma both have to be positive and one can bound mu from below by max(data), since mu is the upper right point of the distribution. 
In point 2 I asked, whether there are situations when supplying the gradient is contraproductive. Do you know any of them (besides the obvious one that my ll is uncontinous or widely unsmooth. 

Thank you for your answer, it already gave me a lot of insights and new ideas to try.

Comment: One situation where it is bad to supply the gradient is when you code it wrong.  (I have done that several times.)  Often numerical estimates of the gradient are good enough, so I usually don't bother with it.

Comment: Okay, funnily enough I am very suspicous about me having coded the gradient correctly since there is an error message " Error: Gradient function might be wrong - check it!" from the optimx procedure... But I used the numderiv package to check max distances of my analytical derivative and the numeric one. The result was that the distance was at most of order 1e-7, from which I conclude, that the analytical gradient is correct...

I'm surprised at how many problems a simple optimization produces...

Comment: John Nash comments in a now-deleted comment: "The OP has a variable name clash in his function call. ¶ I believe I have fixed this in a major review and revision of optimx, which is a VERY complicated package. It will, however, not be on CRAN for quite a while due to the checking CRAN requires. Interested users can contact nashjc at uottawa.ca to get the new package in beta."

Comment: Thank you, for stating the content of his comment. It was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

https://web.ncf.ca/nashjc/optimx202112/  has a version of the package that deals with at least some variable clashes in the dot args.

There are some separate cleanups to be done before this goes on CRAN, but
the package should be more or less robust at the moment.

JN

Comment: Are you the author of the linked package? If yes, I think you need to disclose your affiliation.

Comment: Yes. Actually I've disclosed that in a couple of previous posts, where I asked if those experiencing trouble could contact me so I could do the fix. but the posts were deleted because the deleter claimed I wasn't actually providing an answer. I guess some people not only want dinner, they want someone to hold the spoon that feeds them. Sigh. And CRAN style packages have the full attribution in the DESCRIPTION, so the authorship is clear. For information, there is still work that needs to be done before I resubmit to CRAN, but I think the issue raised in this thread is mostly sorted out.

Comment: Thank you for answering and the hint to a version which deals with variable clashes!